# Accumulating data points into a list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Here is my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
n := 1000
sollist = {{}}
t = 0; While[t < 10, (n = (1 - 0.025)*n; t = t + 0.05;
Print[{t, n}];
Append[sollist, {t, n}])]
ListPlot[sollist]
```

However, the list `soloist` is empty after the execution. Anyone has any ideas why that is the case? How should I modify the code?

Comment: Replace `sollist = {{}}` with `sollist = {}` and `Append` with `AppendTo`?

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the code with `Table[]`, this way is rather inefficient.

Comment: I'd say it is a duplicate: [common pitfalls /  Assuming commands will have side effects when they don't](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/5478)

Comment: @Kuba. You're right, but a beginner can't deduce what to do to fix the problem from that post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a repaired version of your code.

```
data = {};
With[{dt = .2},
  Module[{n = 1000, t = 0},
    While[t < 10,
      n = (1 - .5 dt)*n;
      AppendTo[data, {t, n}];
      t = t + dt]]]
```

But there is an easier way.

```
data = 
  With[{dt = .2}, 
    Module[{n = 1000}, Table[{t, n = (1 - .5 dt) n}, {t, 0, 10, dt}]]];
```

In either case the plot looks like

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `NestList[]` ought to be also usable here.

Comment: @J.M. Probably, but would it give any real advantage over `Table`? We're dealing with a beginner here; for that reason, I thought `Table` would be the best thing to suggest.